# preg_replace not working on groups of symbols

Tags: php, preg-replace

So I am trying to make a morse code encoder/decoder; I got the encoder done, but the decoder is giving me some problems.

So, if I use the function **test** and input "ab" it will return "ab". If however, I input "a b" it returns "c d" (as it should, 100% working)

```
function test($code){
    $search = array('/\ba\b/', '/\bb\b/');
    $replace = array('c', 'd');
    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $code);
}
```

**BUT** when I use the function **morsedecode** and input ".- -..." it doesn't do anything and retuns ".- -...".

```
function morsedecode($code){
    $search = array('/\b.-\b/', '/\b-...\b/');
    $replace = array('a', 'b');
    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $code);
}
```

I am stuck because it doesn't seem to be working for symbols, as it does for letters and words. Does anyone know the reason for this and is there anyway to work around this in PHP?

Comment: You've jumped right into the problem without given an actual problem description.

Comment: `.` and `-` are special charecters in regex. If your trying to match them literaly, you need to escape them.

Comment: @Mohamed Mufeed, so is there another PHP function that can search for groups of dots & dashes to replace them? EDIT: or what are some symbols that ARENT special chars in regex and are a bit rare-ish?

Comment: @Crimin4L special charecter does not mean you can’t match them. You can. But you need to escape them eg. `.` becomes `\.` and `-` becomes `\-`

Comment: Also I ve been googling, it seems your version of morsecode seems wrong because according to [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) you need one space between each .|- In the same letter, three space between each letter and 7 spaces between each word, what is your version? I don’t see any spaces

Comment: I mean how do you seperate words and letters?

Comment: Letters are separated by spaces (" ") and words are separated by space-slash-space (" / "). Every different website seems to use a different format, I went with this format from this website: https://morsecode.world/international/translator.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

If all your characters are surrounded by spaces (or beginning/end of line), you will probably find it easier to use [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) rather than a regex based approach. Since `strtr` replaces longest matches first, you don't have to worry about (for example) `-.-` (`k`) being partially replaced as `-a`.

```
function morsedecode($code){
    $search = array('.-', '-...');
    $replace = array('a', 'b');
    return strtr($code, array_combine($search, $replace));
}

echo morsedecode(".- -...");
```

Output:

```
a b
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ie57S)

**Original Answer**

Your problem is that `\b` matches a word boundary i.e. the place where the character to the left is a word character (`a-zA-Z0-9_`) and the character to the right a non-word character (or vice versa). Since you have no word characters in your input string, you can never match a word boundary. Instead, you could use lookarounds for a character which is not a dot or a dash:

```
function morsedecode($code){
    $search = array('/(?<![.-])\.-(?![.-])/', '/(?<![.-])-\.\.\.(?![.-])/');
    $replace = array('a', 'b');
    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $code);
}

echo morsedecode(".- -...");
```

Output

```
a b
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OkkWt)

Note that `.` is a special character in regex (matching any character) and  needs to be escaped, otherwise it will match a `-` as well as a `.`.

Comment: Probably would've been easier than what I ended up doing. But thank you for the great answer bud, never knew I could replace things using strstr :P
See below for what I ended up doing.

Comment: Also funny how you already knew what I was fighting with while using str_replace (-.- (k) being partially replaced as -a) so I reverted to preg_replace to solve it but hit another wall haha. Appreciate the knowledge dump though <3

Comment: @Crimin4L yeah, I've run into this sort of problem a few times. `strtr` is really useful for cases when you want to match short strings which can also be substrings of longer strings you also want to match.

Comment: Just updated my code to use the strstr & array_combine function mentioned in your updated response and let me tell you, works like a charm; So simple! Thank you once again bud :)

Answer (score 1):

`\b` is a word boundary, which is any of the following.

1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

`'/\b.-\b/'`
The first does `\b` not match in `.- -...` because of #1. Specifically `if the first character is a word character`

A word character = `ASCII letter, digit or underscore` so `.` is not a word character.

Also, you need to escape `.` characters like `\.`.

Try looking for `\s*` (any number of white spaces) instead of a word boundary.

```
function morsedecode($code){
    $search = array('/\s*\.-\s*/', '/\s*-\.\.\.\s*/');
    $replace = array('a', 'b');
    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $code);
}
```

Example
https://regex101.com/r/LCZXCn/1

Comment: This will match `-.-` https://regex101.com/r/LCZXCn/2

Comment: @Nick yeah I thought about that. Honestly he is going to have bigger problems unless he is splitting the string on whitespace and comparing the longest morse code string possible to the input or he is using the `^` and $` anchors and matching the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up coming up with my own little fix for the problem:

```
    function morsedecode($code){
        $bd_code = str_replace(array('.', '-', '/'), array('dot', 'dash', '~slash~'), $code);
        $search = array('/\bdotdash\b/', '/\bdashdotdotdot\b/', '/\bdashdotdashdot\b/', 'etc..');
        $replace = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'etc..');
        $string =  preg_replace($search, $replace, $bd_code);
        return str_replace(array(' ', '~slash~'), array('', ' '), $string);
    }
```

Definitely not the most efficient but gets the job done. @Nick answer is definitely an efficient way to go.

Comment: This is the other way to do it. Painful but functional :)